# Asp.Net Linq and XML query

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to grab some data using LINQ and a "WHERE" function within my "SELECT" function

Here's my sample XML

```
<Items>
<Extras>
    <Extra Code="TEST1" Quantity="1" />
    <Extra Code="TEST2" Quantity="1" />
</Extras>

<Options>
    <OptionalExtra Description="Test 1" Code="TEST1" type="TESTING1" />
    <OptionalExtra Description="Test 2" Code="TEST2" type="TESTING2"  />
</Options>
</Items>
```

And here's my LINQ query

```
bookingsInfo = xel.Descendants("Extras").Descendants("Extra") _
  .Select(Function(f) New With { _
    .Code = f.Attributes("Code").First.Value, _
    .Type = f.Parent.Parent.Descendants("Options").Descendants("OptionalExtra") _
            .Where(Function(g) g.Attributes("Code").First.Value = _
            f.Attributes("Code").First.Value).Attributes("type").First.Value, _
    .Quantity = f.Attributes("Quantity").First.Value _
})
```

The "TYPE" is the problem I'm having trouble getting and I'm not really sure what the issue is.

I don't have any control of how the XML is laid out but I can edit the LINQ query no problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your XML doesn't *have* a type attribute... so what are you trying to get?

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet I had missed that bit out when I was typing it in! See update

Comment: Okay, so now it's there, and we know that's "the problem" - but you haven't actually described what that problem *is*. What is the query meant to do, and what happens at the moment?

Comment: The query is producing "CODE" and "QUANTITY" as these are just attributes but when I'm trying to go up to the parents and then into the other extras to get the "TYPE" where the "CODE" matches in each it's failing and giving me a "Sequence contains no elements" - does that make sense? Sorry for not being more descriptive in my OP

Comment: No, it doesn't really make sense. It would be much easier to follow if you'd show a short but complete program with the expected output and the actual output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier to use `Join` instead of `Parent.Parent`:

```
Dim bookingsInfo = From e In xel.Root.<Extras>.<Extra>
                   Join o In xel.Root.<Options>.<OptionalExtra> On e.@Code Equals o.@Code
                   Select New With { 
                       .Code = e.@Code,
                       .Type = o.@Type,
                       .Quantity = e.@Quantity
                   }
```

Comment: Thanks - this works perfectly, I didn't realise you could use LINQ in this way it's so much easier than the way I've been taught!